# Wrong margins for 2-side printing

Tags: margins, texshop

A paper I wrote for 2-sided 3-hole-punch handouts had, on page 1, a wider margin on the right than on the left and, on page two, the left margin was the wider one.

The handout is actually a compact list of formulas to be sold in college book stores for students to carry to math classes or home.

I was using `\documentclass[]{amsart}` but several exchanges and more research showed that `\documentclass[oneside]{amsart}` at least made the margins equal which is less crowding for a 3-hole-punch. This is tolerable but the ideal would be for the left margin to be wider on page 1 and the right margin to be wider on page 2.

Can this be done?

Comment: From a twoside document it is expected that the outer margins are wider than the inner margins.

Comment: Observe that when you open a book, you see an even *and* an odd page, so that you see *two* inner margins side by side,  and that is wider than the outer margin.

Comment: I want the wide margin to be on the left of page $1$ so lit works well in a 3-ring binder. How do I make it so?

Comment: All I am asking is, "Is there a way to override the default?"

Comment: The margins with `amsart` are equal because the output is used directly to create plates for a printing press, and that is where adjustments are made.  It's possible to change this but I haven't time at the moment to work out the modifications.  Often, the `geometry` package is recommended for this; there may be another question here that provides an answer.

Answer (score 1):

See if the use of the `geometry` package solve your problem:

```
\documentclass{amsart} % two side document
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

\begin{document}
 \lipsum\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
From your comments can be understood that you like to have wider inner border from outer. This you can achieve with the following preamble for above MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[hmargin={2in, 1in}]{geometry}
```

for two side document, and

```
\documentclass[oneside]{amsart}
\usepackage[hmargin={2in, 1in}]{geometry}
```

for one side document. With this prreamnle the page layout is:

[image]

For more details for settings of page layout by use the `geometry` package see its documentation. It is part of yopur LaTeX instalation, or you can find it on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry?lang=en) .

Comment: Sounds good but it had no affect once I used [oneside]. If you have any thing that can make page one wider on the left, you will win.

Comment: @poetasis, with my suggestion the page margins are the same at one`oneside` and at `twoside` pages. Size of marins is determined by option `margin=1in`. (or equivalently `borders=1in`).  With it you can set desired size of margins. I was understood you that this is your request. If it is not, please edit your question and provide an example of document where you by hand indicate, desired size of page margins. See edited answer.

Comment: @Teepeemm, ups, I now i see that code is not properly formatted. Now is corrected and the first line of the preamble (where are differences between examples) is now visible.

Comment: I tried variations of   `margin=` but it made no difference while [oneside] was present. I'm looking for a wider left margin on page 1. The equal margins are OK, just not ideal for my purpose here.

Answer (score 0):

I found I could at least make my margins equal by using

`\documentclass[oneside]{amsart}`

and that is acceptable for the 3-hole-punch 2-sided handouts I want to make.